# How to fix direct access but not query links?

Tags: php

So trying to stop `profile.php` file to direct acess but want to acess by query like `profile.php?id=1` but both are redirecting to index. Cant add .htaccess cause it's in my root folder. Any help will be so much pleasure for me.

```
`<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('navbar.php'); ?>`
```

Comment: This code you are write on your profilr.php?

Comment: yes it's the in the profile.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you don't access to .htaccess

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }
    include('header.php');
    include('navbar.php');
} else
{
    //you can do which you want either redirect or anything
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's stopping direct access and also redirecting `profile.php?id=1` this page to header location

Comment: Means you want if anyone send requests on profile.php then you want to redirect on profile.php?id=1